# Retrieving items in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How can i retrieve items in arraylist and convert it to image simultaneously?

sample codes:

```
public void translateLetter(View v){
    String[] let = letters.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> call = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(let));
    for (int i = 0; i < call.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] .equals(call)){
            aslImages.setImageResource(aslPic[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the contents in `call`? Are they URLs or resource ids?

Comment: they are resource ids...from the drawable...it was images...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str[i].equals(call)) {...}
```

I think it should be  :-

```
if (str[i].equals(call.get(i))) {...}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it can only retrieved the last index of the arraylist.. i wanted to retrieve all of items(words) in arraylist after i splitted a sentence.. because i need to convert it one by one into image. please help. godbless

Comment: your if block is in `for-loop`, it will retrieve all elements on iteration

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're asking, but I believe you need to use the `List.get(int i)` method

```
if (str[i].equals(call.get(i))) { .. }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it can only retrieved the last index of the arraylist.. i wanted to retrieve all of items(words)  in arraylist after i splitted a sentence.. because i need to convert it one by one into image. please help. godbless

Comment: Since the `if` statement is within a `for` loop, it will retrieve every word.